# How to integrate stripe in my Nuxt3 project

Tags: stripe-payments, nuxt3

I had a working configuration with Nuxt3/Stripe I implemented a few months ago but I can not get it to work now.

I'm using a route middleware with Nuxt3 to check wether there is a stripe active subscription before loading paid content pages.

This middleware imports the stripe module with:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe'
```

As soon as the line gets executed, I get a "500 [vite-node] [ERR_LOAD_URL] express" (even if I remove any stripe code below).

Do you know what is wrong in my configuration?

Or do you have a working example of a Nuxt3 compatible stripe configuration?
I tried the vue-stripe module but it is not compatible with Nuxt3.
I also tried the nuxt-stripe-module with no success.

Thanks a lot!
Samuel

Comment: Where does `import Stripe from 'stripe'` come from? I'm assuming you're using stripe-node in which case you'd want `const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');` instead from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the page you point to, there is below an example using ES module with import Stripe from 'stripe'. Require does not work with Nuxt3

Comment: Are you using stripe-node though for your server-side code? Or are you trying to use Stripe.js client-side in your frontend code?

Comment: Hi. According to the documentation, stripe-node is deprecated and the same library works for front and backend. In any case, I tried both ways (front and back) and get the same error. Thanks for your insights

Comment: stripe-node is absolutely not deprecated. It is the library you use server-side for Node.js environments using your Secret API key. I'm sorry but you seem to be mixing up multiple concepts together. I'd recommend contacting Stripe's support team and sharing your exact set up and they can help you: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to call stripe from the client side.

When using

`import Stripe from 'stripe'`

on the server side (nuxt middleware page) with stripe npm library, it worked like a charm.